# want to implement websockets using ratchet in php

Tags: php, php-7, ratchet

I have a situation where I want to display dynamic data that is received from this API `wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/btcusdt@depth`. I want to use `ratchet` and I  have written code like this

```
require __DIR__ . '\vendor\autoload.php';
use Ratchet\MessageComponentInterface;
use Ratchet\ConnectionInterface;

\Ratchet\Client\connect('wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/btcusdt@depth')->then(function($conn) {
    $conn->on('message', function($msg) use ($conn) {
        echo "Received: {$msg}\n";
      //  $conn->close();
    });

   // $conn->send('Hello World!');
}, function ($e) {
    echo "Could not connect: {$e->getMessage()}\n";
});
```

but here its giving me the following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function Ratchet\Client\connect()
```

I'm not sure where to look for the error.

Comment: let me install that

Comment: its working now thanks a lot @PaulCrovella